# Como visualizar a posição x e y de um elemento pelo DevTools do Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão, dev-tools

Alguém poderia me dizer se há alguma forma de visualizar o X e Y de um objeto de tela com o Inspect do DevTools do Chrome, ou alguma extensão que permita isso?

O DevTools mostra o tamanho do objeto quando passa-se o mouse sobre ele usando o Inspect, porem não exibe a posição do mesmo.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso uma extensão do Chrome que chama **Page Rule** 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/emliamioobfffbgcfdchabfibonehkme

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que ela da a posição `X / Y` do elemento.

Segue abaixo o exemplo de uso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era exatamente isto que eu estava procurando. Utilizo algumas extensões de régua (rule) mas nenhuma me dá essa informação de forma tão prática e fácil como esta que você me indicou.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: @EleisonChristiano que bom que resolveu, ela é bem prática mesmo! :)